# Updating UI from IOS library

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could somebody give me guidance/starting point on how I would update a UI Text Label in an IOS app from a **library**.

I have temperature data being received from  a BT module in a **library** connected to my app. I want to send that Integer data to my app and update the UI Text label.

NOTE: I have full access to the library.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Because this shows no research -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is a way to provide feedback to an application from your Cocoa static library.

I would suggest that you have a look at the `NSNotificationCenter` class. For example, say that you have a class `BTThermometer` that, upon the reception of a new measurement calls:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.my.BTThermometer.NewValue" object:self];
```

Then, in you application, you could do something like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"com.my.BTThermometer.NewValue" object:self queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification* n) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        someLabel.text = ((BTThermometer*)n.object).temperatureValue;
    }
}];
```

This is a standard mechanism in iOS to decouple your application from the internal workings of your library. The only coupling is the name itself, and of course it is usually a good idea to use a constant (e.g. `#define kMyTemperatureEvent @"com.my.BTThermometer.NewValue`) so that the compiler catches any typos.